# Android GL How to draw different textures

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

I'm in troubles with Android, GL and Textures, I have a little example and I want to load two different textures and paint it on screen, my problem is that always draws the last texture loaded.

I'm noob with GL in android and have copied the code from some tutorials.

Here is the code:

GLRenderer:

```
public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

    // Our matrices
    private final float[] mtrxProjection = new float[16];
    private final float[] mtrxView = new float[16];
    private final float[] mtrxProjectionAndView = new float[16];

    // Our screenresolution
    float   mScreenWidth = 1280;
    float   mScreenHeight = 768;

    // Misc
    Context mContext;
    long mLastTime;
    int mProgram;

    CardView card1;
    CardView card2;

    public GLRenderer(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
        mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 100;
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        /* Do stuff to pause the renderer */
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        /* Do stuff to resume the renderer */
        mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Get the current time
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // We should make sure we are valid and sane
        if (mLastTime > now) return;

        // Get the amount of time the last frame took.
        long elapsed = now - mLastTime;

        // Update our example

        // Render our example
        card1.Draw(mtrxProjectionAndView);
        card2.Draw(mtrxProjectionAndView);

        // Save the current time to see how long it took :).
        mLastTime = now;

    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

        // We need to know the current width and height.
        mScreenWidth = width;
        mScreenHeight = height;

        // Redo the Viewport, making it fullscreen.
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int)mScreenWidth, (int)mScreenHeight);

        // Clear our matrices
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            mtrxProjection[i] = 0.0f;
            mtrxView[i] = 0.0f;
            mtrxProjectionAndView[i] = 0.0f;
        }

        // Setup our screen width and height for normal sprite translation.
        Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, 0f, mScreenWidth, 0.0f, mScreenHeight, 0, 50);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mtrxView, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        card1 = new CardView(mContext, 1);
        card2 = new CardView(mContext, 2);
    }
}


public class CardView {

    // Misc
    private Context mContext;

    // Geometric variables
    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    private static float vertices[] = {
            10.0f, 300f, 0.0f,
            10.0f, 100f, 0.0f,
            450f, 100f, 0.0f,
            450f, 300f, 0.0f,
    };
    private static float vertices2[] = {
            450.0f, 600f, 0.0f,
            450.0f, 300f, 0.0f,
            900f, 300f, 0.0f,
            900f, 600f, 0.0f,
    };

    private final short indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
    private static float uvs[] = {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer uvBuffer;


    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    public CardView(Context c, int index)
    {
        // Save context reference
        mContext = c;
        // Create the triangles
        SetupCard(index);
        // Create the image information
        SetupImage(index);

        // Set the clear color to black
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);

        // Create the shaders, solid color
        int vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_SolidColor);
        int fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_SolidColor);

        riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables

        // Create the shaders, images
        vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_Image);
        fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_Image);

        riGraphicTools.sp_Image = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables


        // Set our shader programm
        GLES20.glUseProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);
    }



    public void SetupImage(int index)
    {
        // The texture buffer
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        uvBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        uvBuffer.put(uvs);
        uvBuffer.position(0);

        // Generate Textures, if more needed, alter these numbers.
        int[] texturenames = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texturenames, 0);

        // Retrieve our image from resources.
        //int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/test_backbground1", null, mContext.getPackageName());
        if(index == 1) {
            int id = riGraphicTools.loadTexture(mContext, R.drawable.test_backbground1, index);
        }else{
            int id = riGraphicTools.loadTexture(mContext, R.drawable.test_backbground2, index);
        }

    }


    public void SetupCard(int index)
    {

        if( index == 1) {
            // The vertex buffer.
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);
        }else{
            // The vertex buffer.
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices2.length * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices2);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);
        }

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(indices);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);


    }

    /**
     * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
     *
     * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
     * this shape.
     */

    public void Draw(float[] mvpMatrix){

        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer, we have set the clear color as black.
        //GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "vPosition");

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // Get handle to texture coordinates location
        int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "a_texCoord" );

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

        // Prepare the texturecoordinates
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false,
                0, uvBuffer);

        // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "uMVPMatrix");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        // Get handle to textures locations
        int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "s_texture" );

        // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
        GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

    }
}


public class riGraphicTools {

    private static final String TAG = "GraphicTools";

    // Program variables
    public static int sp_SolidColor;
    public static int sp_Image;


    /* SHADER Solid
     *
     * This shader is for rendering a colored primitive.
     *
     */
    public static final String vs_SolidColor =
            "uniform    mat4        uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute  vec4        vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    public static final String fs_SolidColor =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5,0,0,1);" +
                    "}";

    /* SHADER Image
     *
     * This shader is for rendering 2D images straight from a texture
     * No additional effects.
     *
     */
    public static final String vs_Image =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +
                    "}";

    public static final String fs_Image =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
                    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );" +
                    "}";




    /**
     * Utility method for compiling a OpenGL shader.
     *
     * <p><strong>Note:</strong> When developing shaders, use the checkGlError()
     * method to debug shader coding errors.</p>
     *
     * @param type - Vertex or fragment shader type.
     * @param shaderCode - String containing the shader code.
     * @return - Returns an id for the shader.
     */
    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        // return the shader
        return shader;
    }



    /**
     * Utility method for debugging OpenGL calls. Provide the name of the call
     * just after making it:
     *
     * <pre>
     * mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
     * FandeckRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");</pre>
     *
     * If the operation is not successful, the check throws an error.
     *
     * @param glOperation - Name of the OpenGL call to check.
     */
    public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

    public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId, int[] textureHandler, int index)
    {

        //GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandler, index);

        if (textureHandler[index] != 0)
        {
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

            // Read in the resource
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandler[index]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

            // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

            // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
            bitmap.recycle();
        }

        if (textureHandler[index] == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        }

        return textureHandler[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the textureHandle, I have moved it to upper class to keep data, and in the method Draw I have added:

```
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[textureIndex]);
```

and it works.

the final code is the next one:

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

```
// Our matrices
private final float[] mtrxProjection = new float[16];
private final float[] mtrxView = new float[16];
private final float[] mtrxProjectionAndView = new float[16];

// Our screenresolution
float   mScreenWidth = 1280;
float   mScreenHeight = 768;

// Misc
Context mContext;
long mLastTime;
int mProgram;

CardView card1;
CardView card2;

public GLRenderer(Context c)
{
    mContext = c;
    mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 100;
}

public void onPause()
{
    /* Do stuff to pause the renderer */
}

public void onResume()
{
    /* Do stuff to resume the renderer */
    mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Get the current time
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // We should make sure we are valid and sane
    if (mLastTime > now) return;

    // Get the amount of time the last frame took.
    long elapsed = now - mLastTime;

    // Update our example

    // Render our example
    card1.Draw(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);

    card2.Draw(mtrxProjectionAndView , 1);

    // Save the current time to see how long it took :).
    mLastTime = now;

}


@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    // We need to know the current width and height.
    mScreenWidth = width;
    mScreenHeight = height;

    // Redo the Viewport, making it fullscreen.
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int)mScreenWidth, (int)mScreenHeight);

    // Clear our matrices
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        mtrxProjection[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxView[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxProjectionAndView[i] = 0.0f;
    }

    // Setup our screen width and height for normal sprite translation.
    Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, 0f, mScreenWidth, 0.0f, mScreenHeight, 0, 50);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mtrxView, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    card1 = new CardView(mContext, 0);
    card2 = new CardView(mContext, 1);
}
```

}

public class CardView {

```
// Misc
private Context mContext;

// Geometric variables
// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
private static float vertices[] = {
        10.0f, 300f, 0.0f,
        10.0f, 100f, 0.0f,
        450f, 100f, 0.0f,
        450f, 300f, 0.0f,
};
private static float vertices2[] = {
        450.0f, 600f, 0.0f,
        450.0f, 300f, 0.0f,
        900f, 300f, 0.0f,
        900f, 600f, 0.0f,
};

private final short indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
private static float uvs[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
};
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private FloatBuffer uvBuffer;


private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

final int[] textureHandle;

public CardView(Context c, int index)
{

    textureHandle = new int[2];
    // Save context reference
    mContext = c;
    // Create the triangles
    SetupCard(index);
    // Create the image information
    SetupImage(index);

    // Set the clear color to black
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);

    // Create the shaders, solid color
    int vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_SolidColor);
    int fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_SolidColor);

    riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables

    // Create the shaders, images
    vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_Image);
    fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_Image);

    riGraphicTools.sp_Image = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables


    // Set our shader programm
    GLES20.glUseProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);
}



public void SetupImage(int index)
{

    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, textureHandle, 0);

    // The texture buffer
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    uvBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    uvBuffer.put(uvs);
    uvBuffer.position(0);

    // Generate Textures, if more needed, alter these numbers.
    int[] texturenames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texturenames, 0);

    // Retrieve our image from resources.
    //int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/test_backbground1", null, mContext.getPackageName());
    if(index == 1) {
        int id = riGraphicTools.loadTexture(mContext, R.drawable.test_backbground1, textureHandle, index);
    }else{
        int id = riGraphicTools.loadTexture(mContext, R.drawable.test_backbground2, textureHandle, index);
    }

}


public void SetupCard(int index)
{

    if( index == 1) {
        // The vertex buffer.
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
    }else{
        // The vertex buffer.
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices2.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices2);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(indices);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);


}

/**
 * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
 *
 * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
 * this shape.
 */

public void Draw(float[] mvpMatrix, int textureIndex){

    // clear Screen and Depth Buffer, we have set the clear color as black.
    //GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[textureIndex]);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "vPosition");

    // Enable generic vertex attribute array
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // Get handle to texture coordinates location
    int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "a_texCoord" );

    // Enable generic vertex attribute array
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

    // Prepare the texturecoordinates
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            0, uvBuffer);

    // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    // Get handle to textures locations
    int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "s_texture" );

    // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
    GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

}
```

}

public class riGraphicTools {

```
// Program variables
public static int sp_SolidColor;
public static int sp_Image;


/* SHADER Solid
 * 
 * This shader is for rendering a colored primitive.
 * 
 */
public static final String vs_SolidColor =
    "uniform    mat4        uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute  vec4        vPosition;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "}";

public static final String fs_SolidColor =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5,0,0,1);" +
    "}"; 

/* SHADER Image
 * 
 * This shader is for rendering 2D images straight from a texture
 * No additional effects.
 * 
 */
public static final String vs_Image =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +
    "}";

public static final String fs_Image =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );" +
    "}"; 



public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    // return the shader
    return shader;
}

public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId, int[] textureHandle , int index)
{

    if (textureHandle[index] != 0)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[index]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    if (textureHandle[index] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[index];
}
```

}

I hope that will help someone.